# Excel Numeric Format Data

Tags: excel, macos, excel-2010, citrix

I have this data that I exports from some ERP in Citrix to the same Excel in Citrix,

[image]

Some example when i paste:

```
Doc.Curr.
-4,248,057.00
-25,998,733.00
25,998,733.00
-192,534.00
-118,509.00
192,534.00
```

But when i export this to a Excel in MacOS doesnt recognize like a number format, only like data without format, how can i solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many systems that export to Excel produce text instead of number. This has to do with the way that the system report was built in the exporting system. For example, the system report uses spaces to separate report columns. Excel parses the data according to the spacing but will not convert the text to numbers. In such a case you need to do that yourself

There are [several ways to convert text to numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885), including

- copy a cell with a zero, use paste special to paste over the text that should be numbers, using the option to "Add"
- use text to columns on one column of numbers

If you need to do that on a regular basis, you may want to look into Power Query (Get and Transform) to load the data and perform any cleanup in there. It will be faster in the long run.